# Extract and format file name from directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to grab the name of a file from a directory in PS, and then populate it in an email using the line below:

```
Get-ChildItem \\sp_dran\BSRP\PROF\SUC\BSRP\Outbound\INTP\*.txt | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1 | select Name
```

I am able to grab the name, however it comes out with extra characters, which looks sloppy:

```
@{Name=YT-Rixinx-20210331.txt}
```

Is there a way just to grab the name ( YT-Rixinx-20210331.txt) without the extra characters and symbols around it?

Comment: Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` instead of `select Name`. BTW: That's basics of  PowerShell lesson 1.  :-/ You would have got this info by googling in 10 seconds.

Comment: Teaching yourself means doing proper research before asking the question, did you honestly do this before asking ? Did you care to at least read the MS Docs for `Get-ChildItem` and `Select-Object` before posting ? Not doing this before asking means, in my opinion, not showing respect to the community trying to help you :)

Comment: What Olaf/Santiago gave you are all valid points. So, they are not really being rude, but using the old adage, `Give a man a fish, he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish and they will eat for a lifetime.` I've been doing IT for over 4 decades, and always take the time to learn from anyone/anytime. One can learn from anyone no matter what the skill level; yet, only, if they are willing. No one knows everything/never will, but shutting down folks providing direction/edification is not prudent. All here is about community give back/sharing/guidance, etc, not just a `give me an answer ` shop.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, it's best to surround strings in quotes (single for simple strings, double in places where needed, i.e., variable expansion, formatting requirements, etc.), this helps Powershell be more specific in its helpfulness efforts.

It is very odd that you are getting this...

```
@{Name=YT-Rixinx-20210331.txt}
```

... which is an array/collection indication, vs just this...

```
YT-Rixinx-20210331.txt
```

...since you are only asking for one thing. This really should not be happening on a simple `gci\dir\ls` command. So, something else is odd in your environment.

Yet, if this is an array, then you need to use the [-ExpandProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-8--demonstrate-the-intricacies-of-the--expandproperty-parameter) switch/property for [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1),

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Select-Object).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Select-Object).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
InputObject
Property
ExcludeProperty
ExpandProperty
Unique
Last
First
Skip
SkipLast
Wait
Index
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
#>
Get-help -Name Select-Object -Examples
Get-Help -Name Select-Object -Detailed
Get-help -Name Select-Object -Full
Get-help -Name Select-Object -Online
```

...or, try it this way `(dot referencing)`. Since you are only asking for 1 property, using Select-Object is extra stuff.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\*.txt' | 
Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 1).Name
```

You could easily just done this as well, thus eliminating the need to `Select-Object` at all.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\*.txt' | 
Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending).Name[0]
```